# React the application does not execute a request to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The application works correctly on the local server, executes a request to Firebase and provides information from it.

But the deploy version does not fulfill the request to firebase in any way. I don't understand what could be the problem?

Firebase configuration in the application
`

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyDjRWZ9**********QwkgyqTeVbN*',
    authDomain: 'project-keeper-2a3fe.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL:
        'https://******.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app',
    projectId: 'project-keeper-2a3fe',
    storageBucket: 'project-keeper-2a3fe.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '495347609056',
    appId: '1:495347609056:web:d058a40ddff6b5420ecf85',
    measurementId: 'G-SKDZVBKHN5'
}

export default firebaseConfig
```

`

Initializing firebase in the application
`

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

import firebaseConfig from '../../config/firebaseConfig'

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = getFirestore(app)
const auth = getAuth(app)

const analytics = getAnalytics(app)

export { db }
```

`

Executing a request to firestore
`

```
import { db } from '../../shared/api/firebase/firebase'
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore'


export const CardsListPage = () => {
    const [cards, setCards] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        return async () => {
            const colRef = collection(db, 'cards')
            const snapshots = await getDocs(colRef)
            const docs = snapshots.docs?.map(doc => {
                const data = doc.data()
                data.id = doc.id
                return data
            })
            setCards(docs)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Header />

            <main className='main'>
                <div className='main-container'>
                    <div className='main-container__cards'>
                        {cards.map(card => (
                            <Card key={card.id} {...card} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
...
```

`

I don't understand what the problem might be. Everything works on the local server, but not on the hosting

[Requests to firebase on the local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF8tq.png)
[Requests to firebase on a remote server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugexS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I might think of you not added `firebaseConfig` file to hosting. It works fine on locally but as you ignored or not added any config files(because it has secret keys) it might not work.

Also I could think of some ENV variables that you didn't added to your hosting
server if they exists. (In that case, ENV's prefix should be `REACT_APP_`. ex. `REACT_APP_MY_SECRET_KEY`)

Comment: I made an env, checked the integrity of the files on the hosting. But still nothing is loaded

https://ibb.co/Bq6wmMR